# Laravel 3 - why does sending parameters to Redirect::to_route not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am wondering why the parameters aren't recognized in this way:

```
return Redirect::to_route('new_snippet', array(Input::get('snippet'), $validation_errors[0]));
```

or this way:

```
 return Redirect::to_action('snippet@new', array(Input::get('snippet'), $validation_errors[0]));
```

while they are in this manner

```
return $this->get_new(Input::get('snippet'), $validation_errors[0]);
```

by calling this function in the controller:

```
    public function get_new($default_snippet = '', $error = null)
    {
        #code
    }
```

I hope that anyone can briefly explain this. I am asking because this only works if all of it happens in the same controller.

Thanks

Comment: Which version, `L3` or `L4` ?

Comment: It is Laravel 3. I was already wondering if this would work in Laravel 4

Comment: In `L4` it's `return Redirect::route('route_name', array(1));` not `to_route`.

Comment: Correct. I checked the source of this version but that still says that the to_route function accepts a second parameter as an array.

Comment: Can you define `not working` ? what actually happens ?

Comment: The parameters are not recognized they are the default value when dumping them.

Comment: Yes, `to_route` also can work with second param.

Comment: Try to dump `Input::get('snippet')` and `$validation_errors[0])` before redirect, to make sure they really exists.